# how to write with LinQ to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
SELECT P.ProductId, P.ProductCategoryId, P.ParentProductCategoryId, 
       P.ProductName, PC.Name AS Category, P.Price, P.ProductYear
FROM   dbo.ProductCategory AS PC 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT dbo.ProductCategory.ParentProductCategoryId, 
          dbo.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryId, 
          dbo.ProductCategory.Name AS CategoryName, 
          dbo.Product.ProductId, 
          dbo.Product.Price, 
          dbo.Product.Name AS ProductName, 
          dbo.Product.ProductYear
   FROM dbo.Product 
   INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategory 
   ON dbo.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryId = dbo.Product.ProductCategoryId
  ) AS P 
ON PC.ProductCategoryId = P.ParentProductCategoryId
```

Comment: Might be worth including example of results you want here...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about your database layout but the LINQ statement would look something like this...

```
YourDataContext db = new YourDataContext();

var query =
    from p in db.Products
    join pc in db.ProductCategories on p.ProductCategoryId equals pc.ProductCategoryId 
    select new 
    {
        p.ProductId,
        p.ProductCategoryId,
        p.ParentProductCategoryId,
        p.ProductName,
        Category = pc.Name,
        p.Price,
        p.ProductYear 
    }
```

Comment: If you look carefully you will notice that the questionner is linking ProductCategories parents to children, and then to Products.

Comment: Ah, it looks like some one has edited the post and used code blocks. Appologies.